# What Windows software can assemble a sequence of photos into a timelapse?

Tags: software, video, timelapse

Do you know any good software for Windows platform that can be used to create a time-lapse video from a bunch of photos? I'm interested in free alternatives, but the paid ones are also OK.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/recommendations-for-time-lapse-photography-software

Comment: I'm looking for a Windows only application

Comment: This: http://www.digital-photography-school.com/how-to-create-a-video-masterpiece-with-your-photos-get-100000-youtube-views suggests you could just use windows movie maker...

Comment: I tried Windows Movie Maker, but it's just a joke :)

Comment: Why is Windows Live Movie Maker a joke? are you looking for any specific functionality?

Comment: Windows Movie Maker is not a joke - once I had combined my images I used it to edit my timelapse video - http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12113/what-settings-should-i-use-for-a-timelapse-of-my-wedding

Comment: `ffmpeg` can do this.  It's a command line program that works on all major platforms, including Windows.  I have used it on Windows to assemble a time lapse.  It's free and relatively easy to use (compared to other command line alternatives).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're not planning on doing much editing, just turning a bunch of photos into a video, you can use [Virtualdub](http://virtualdub.org/). See e.g. [this video](https://vimeo.com/4212195).

For easier editing, there are many video editors out there, but I cannot say for sure which of these that can import an image sequence as a video clip (which is useful). Examples of reasonably priced video editors are Sony Vegas Movie Studio, Adobe Premiere Elements and Magix Movie Edit Pro. Demo versions of all three are available, so you can try them before making a purchase.

Comment: Virtualdub seems really great but I can't see how to open multiples images at once? I have 200+ images I want to convert to avi file but open one by one is a lot of work :(

Comment: @Jack Isn't it described in the video? They have to be numbered sequentially, then select the first one and check some box I think. (Can't remember exactly, and don't have the possibility to check at the moment.)

Answer (score 9):

I use [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) for this task.  It is a command line program that [works well on Windows](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/).

A typical command line would look similar to

```
ffmpeg -r 15 -start_number 1234 -i DSC_%d.jpg -s 1280x852 -vcodec libx264 output.mp4
```

This assumes that your files are named according to the pattern `DSC_1234.jpg` and that the first file is no. 1234.  The framerate is set to 15 frames per second.  Make sure you put the `-r` option before the `-i` option.  Each frame is resized to 1280 by 852 pixels.

You'll need to process the photos with a different program (if you want post-processing), then assemble the frames into a video with ffmpeg.

Comment: I had to use %04d explicitely

Answer (score 3):

I've used LRTimelapse (in conjunction with Lightroom) to make a time lapse of Melbourne skyline.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7U9uVbijT4g

http://lrtimelapse.com/

It has really simple batch processing tools to create nice transitions even if your image sequence "flickers". It comes with presets for Lightroom post-processing and correct settings for video file creation. There are also a number of video guides on their website.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using [Time-Lapse Tool Software](http://www.timelapsetool.com). You can choose folders with images and start a timelapse video encoding almost instantly. The software supports all major video formats like MPEG,  H.264, etc

Comment: Costs at least $69 https://timelapsetool.com/en/Buy

Answer (score 2):

I have found several software in my explorations.

- [Photolapse](http://home.hccnet.nl/s.vd.palen/files/PhotoLapse.exe) - output to avi (needs codecs)
- [yawcam](http://home.bitcom.se/yawcam_files/yawcam_install.exe) - output to .mov (needs quicktime)
- [ImagesToVideo](http://mirror2.cze.cz/imagestovideo/ImagesToVideo.zip) - outputs to .mp4
- [chronolapse](http://chronolapse.googlecode.com/files/chronolapse-exe-win_1.0.7.zip) - several outputs, not successfully used so far. Uses mencoder underneath it.

I use ImagesToVideo & Photolapse
or Yawcam and then [miro video converter](http://stub.inst.avg.com/9a28f8b1bc58b35933270912eadc12d1/MiroVideoConverter_Setup.exehttp://stub.inst.avg.com/9a28f8b1bc58b35933270912eadc12d1/MiroVideoConverter_Setup.exe) to convert to mp4

They choke on different things so I have to play around with all of them.

see related question on superuser

- https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/timelapse
- https://superuser.com/questions/249101/how-can-i-combine-30-000-images-into-a-timelapse-movie
- https://superuser.com/questions/138960/time-lapse-software-for-windows-7

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this, but if you use Lightroom 3, Pixiq has a preset you can use: http://www.pixiq.com/article/lightroom-timelapse-presets-now-updated-to-version-3

Answer (score 0):

I have started using [Quicktime Pro](http://www.apple.com/quicktime/extending/) (for Windows) to simply string JPEGs together. At the moment it is $30 USD. It does not de-flicker, colour grade, or do other fancy things.