# What program can I use to combine approximately 1000 .jpg images into a slideshow video (.mov, .mpg, .avi, or similar)?

Tags: software, post-processing, video

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Timelapse software for Linux](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21089/timelapse-software-for-linux)
>   [What Windows software can assemble a sequence of photos into a timelapse?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21609/what-windows-software-can-assemble-a-sequence-of-photos-into-a-timelapse)

I have a series of photographs that I would like to combine into a slideshow video (a low-resolution slideshow video), in the .mov, .mpg, .avi, or similar format.  I would also like to be able to specify the frame rate; since the photographs are different and not in sequence, I will **not** be using 30 or 24 fps; likely, I will choose something like 3 or 5 fps.  I need a video file format, so PowerPoint or Picasa will not work.

Unfortunately, I am running Windows, so I don't have access to iMovie or iPhoto or any other software on the Mac platform.

I have also tried Windows MovieMaker, but it seems tedious to import 1000 images by hand and drag them individually to the "filmstrip sequencer" in the GUI.

Do you have any suggestions?

**ADDENDUM**

By the way, my input does not necessarily have to be .jpg; it could be .gif, in case that is helpful.

Comment: By 3-5 fps do you mean that you want 3-5 of your images to show each second?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, by 3-5 fps, I mean that I want to show 3-5 frames every second. This is quite fast, but it would be good for my application.

Answer (score 3):

Under Linux (and maybe other OSes) you can use mencoder, the encoder from mplayer. It's GPL and free.

Comment: See http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21089/timelapse-software-for-linux

Answer (score 2):

Sony Vegas Movie Studio will do this easily.  You select the length you want each image to be visible and then drag the images to the timeline (Ctrl+A to select all images).  The length of each image can then be adjusted individually if necessary.  All of the common image formats are acceptable.  As I recall, the trial version is limited to 30 days but is fully functional so you could try it out.

Comment: I second Vegas;  this and its professional counterpart are unsung heroes in the movie editing world for automated editing like you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft makes another free program that makes it really simple.  Photo Story 3 won't let you customize a whole lot, but it does make it quick and easy to roll out a decent looking slideshow.

See https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11132