# What software can I use to stitch together thousands of photos into a time lapse video?

Tags: software, timelapse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recommendations for time-lapse photography software](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/recommendations-for-time-lapse-photography-software)

I have a ContourROAM camera which I want to use to do some time-lapse work. What is some software I could use to stitch together the thousands of photos that are produced by the cam into a time-lapse? I know there are probably "work-around" ways of doing it in iMovie or something, but are there any easy, no-hassle apps designed to do just that? Thanks!

Comment: Also http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21609/what-windows-software-can-assemble-a-sequence-of-photos-into-a-timelapse

Answer (score 3):

Three options:

If you want something simple and dedicated to the task for Mac, then [Time Lapse Assembler](http://www.dayofthenewdan.com/projects/time-lapse-assembler-1) is probably it.

If you are not afraid of the Terminal and running command line apps inside it, then [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) is the best and most powerful.

If you have [QuickTime 7 Pro](http://store.apple.com/us/product/D3380Z/A) you can open the sequence via the File|Open Image Sequence, then save a reference QuickTime movie that you can import into the editor of your choice (iMovie, FCP, Premiere, etc.) to add sound, titles and effects.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Windows, use Windows Live Movie Maker. If you have Mac, use iMovie. You don't have to download or buy anything else. These two are more than enough.