# How to convert huge number of pictures to a short, 30 fps video? (combine frames)

Tags: software, timelapse

I'm trying to make a timelapse video. I do have all the shots (6500) and would like to make a short 30 FPS video (max 30 seconds). 6500 shots at 30 FPS makes a 200 seconds video more or less.

If I use fewer pictures I end up with frames containing people that appear only on single frames.

What I would like to do is to use all images and sort of blend them together, so that the person is visible on more frames.

For instance, let's say a set of 10 images. Dude1 is present on pictures 1-5 and dude 2 is present on pictures 3-10. My desire is that both guys are present in the same frame.

Also something like a "persisting frame" effect would be interesting, so that each frame is overlaid on the next frames for a fraction of a second.

Is there any software that can do this?

I'm on a PC.

Comment: Have you looked at  http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21609/what-windows-software-can-assemble-a-sequence-of-photos-into-a-timelapse and http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21089/timelapse-software-for-linux ?

Comment: yes, I have already seen those. the software that is used normally does not have the functionality I need. (virtual dub, etc..)

Comment: I think you need to use something like ImageMagik (a command line program that can be scripted) to blend sets of 7 frames together into a single image, then you can use VirtualDub etc. to create the video.

Comment: I'm afraid the *functionality you need* isn't automatic : AFAIK, blending multiple pictures while keeping person A from image 1 and person B from image 7 has to be done manually, unless they are not moving (then for each pixel you could keep the more "frequent" color of the 7 colors from the 7 images... Of course the pictures have to be aligned). Anyway, Matlab can do all of that :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your request correctly: You want to have a video of all your 6500 pictures where all those pictures are blended at the same time?`

Comment: @flolilolilo, He wants to blend images together to make each video frame so each image "lasts longer".  So frame 1 in the video would be images 1-5 stacked.  Frame 2 would be images 2-6, frame 3 images 3-7, etc.  So, image 5 would actually contribute to 5 frames of video rather than just one quick frame.  Sounds like an interesting effect - not sure what it would end up looking like.

Comment: @JPhi1618 One should be able to accomplish this relatively easily with any program that supports both layers and a fair bit of automatisation (e.g. After Effects with Extended Script). However, this question definitely would be suited best for video.stackexchange.com .

Comment: @JPhi1618 - The process you describe would leave you with essentially the same number of frames, not the reduced number needed by the OP. :)

Comment: @junkyardsparkle I missed the part where he wanted a 30 second clip. I overlayed it with the 30 FPS I guess.  I still want to see what my way looks like.  Time to set up a timer rig to take some time lapse photos.

Answer (score 1):

This is a video question, let's see what is the future of it.

1. Backup your photos.
2. Resample them to a manageable size. I would batch resample them with a bit of sharpening using IrfanView. https://www.irfanview.com/ I would use 1920 px on the base. You can also crop it to a FullHD aspect ratio.
3. Make a video. I would use Virtual Dub, http://virtualdub.sourceforge.net/ probably using Xvid Codec or something similar https://www.xvid.com/. It takes the first numbered image and loads the rest as an image sequence. Set the framerate and save this as V0.

---

Some math

6500photos / 30fps = 216seconds

216seconds / 30seconds = you need to reduce it by 7

Then we have to do some decisions.

---

As you have plenty of images I would make a 60FPS video which would look nicer on youtube for example. But the trick is similar.

4. On the framerate of virtual dub you can decimate the video by 2, 3 or x number. Let's say you choose to use a 60fps frame rate. You need to decimate the video by 3. Save this version as V1.
5. Open V0 and drop the very first frame of it. Decimate by 3 again and save as V2.
6. Repeat: open, drop 2 initial frames and save as V3.

---

Take a video editor that can use layered videos. One free is Davinci Resolve and another one is HitFilmExpress.

7. Stack the V1, V2, and V3 with a transparency of let's say 33.3%
8. Done. You have 3 images stacked on each other on a time-lapse video.

---

It would be interesting to play with different transparency to somehow simulate different "persistent images" More opacity to V2 and a small one on V1 and V3 or something like that.